# NUnit send TestContext to TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-6

Нужно сделать серию тестов на NUnit, использующих `TestCaseSource` для обработки нескольких тест-кейсов, генерируемых из файла Markdown с названием, совпадающим с именем тестового метода. Для этого есть класс `MdFileTestDataSource` с методом `GetData`, возвращающим список параметров в зависимости от аргументов тестового метода. Для этого необходимо, чтобы `GetData` получал каким-либо образом информацию о тестовом методе - имя и список аргументов (`TestContext` или что-то типа этого).

Примеры тестов:

```cs
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(MdFileDataTestSource), nameof(MdFileDataTestSource.GetData))]
public void RoutesAreNotFound(RoutePlan routePlan)
{
        /*...*/
        Assert.IsFalse(/*...*/);
}
 
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(MdFileDataTestSource), nameof(MdFileDataTestSource.GetData))]
public void SimpleTurnsDurationsAndDistances(RoutePlan routePlan, double expectedDurationInSec, double expectedDistanceInM)
{
        /*...*/
        Assert.IsTrue(/*...*/);
        Assert.IsTrue(/*...*/);
}
```

Класс `MdFileDataTestSource`:

```cs
public class MdFileDataTestSource
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetData()
    {
        var parameters = /*test method arguments*/;
        string methodName = /*test method name*/;
        string fileName = "tests/" + methodName + ".md";
        /*читаем и парсим маркдаун файл*/
        foreach (/*...*/)
            yield return outList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Вся проблема в том, что я в `GetData` не могу никак получить информацию о текущем тестовом методе (имя и параметры).

Comment: Я не совсем понял задумку. Но в общем случае, для каждого тестируемого метода должен быть свой метод, выдающий тестовые параметры. То есть для метода `RoutesAreNotFound` должен быть `GetDataWrongRoutes`, для `SimpleTurnsDurationsAndDistances` - `GetDataDurationsAndDistances`.